# How to select default drop-down option in select list in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, html-select

I have the following select option :

```
<select ng-model="class_name" name="class_name" class="form-control">
<option ng-repeat="t in MemberClass" value="{{t}}">{{t.class_name}}</option>
</select>
```

I want to set default option **MemberClass[0]** to select option. I tried the following code but not working.

The JSON data is coming from Webservice...

```
//To fetch Member Class  
  $http.get('http://192.168.1.6:8080/apartment//member/class/list').then(function(response) {
    $scope.MemberClass = response.data.list;
    $scope.class_name = $scope.MemberClass[0]; // Not working
});
```

Member class JSON data is :

```
[
    {
        "class_id": 1,
        "class_name": "Owner",
        "class_details": "DCE"
    },      
    {
        "class_id": 7,
        "class_name": "Staff "
    },
    {
        "class_id": 10
        "class_name": "Vendor"
    }
]
```

Plunker sample : https://plnkr.co/edit/vVcrmOREkcVBBM2Ynhgv?p=preview
(Am getting error if I not select any option...)

Comment: try ng-options="t as t for t in MemberClass" some time ng-options work well

Comment: But inside dropdown it is comming as [object.Object]

Comment: give me data of MemerClass or just try : ng-options="t as t.name  for t in MemberClass"  where name is property you want to display in drp

Comment: I updated code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [**`ng-options`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for this. It is the preferred way most of the times. Like this:

```
<select ng-model="class_name" ng-options="t as t.class_name for t in MemberClass">
</select>
```

Now, since you have `$scope.class_name` assigned as default value, it will be selected already.

[**working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UqxV6vDFHfEXlcfstVFf?p=preview)

Comment: @PrashanthHarish you are getting entire object.. it's just that my object has only `class_name` in there..

Comment: Am getting error. Am parsing that object as  "class0": [JSON.parse($scope.class_name)], Before I initialized $scope.class_name = "{}"; in the beginning....

Comment: @PrashanthHarish what you can do is have `class_name` as `{}` and not string.. so you won't need to `JSON.parse` it like [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/1wQnLoKjaogWOoulSbkU?p=preview)

Comment: If I not selected any option if I try to submit I get error thats why I used {}..

Comment: @PrashanthHarish you won't need to have `JSON.parse` there since selected `class_name` would already be a JSON. [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AUMdfnP51nhdQ96Hcsxd?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-init`. Try like below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Member Class </label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
     <select ng-model="class_name"
   ng-init=" class_name = MemberClass[0]" name="class_name" ng-options="t as t.sub_class_name for t in MemberClass">     
     </select>
    <p>Selected Value: {{class_name}} <p>
     </div>
      </div>
   
   <button type="submit" ng-click="alertdata()">Save</button>
      
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
 
 var MemberClass;
  $scope.MemberClass = [{
                "sub_class_id": 1,
                "sub_class_name": "Primary"
            },
            {
                "sub_class_id": 2,
                "sub_class_name": "Secondary "
            },
            {
                "sub_class_id": 3,
                "sub_class_name": "Dependent "
            },
            {
                "sub_class_id": 4,
                "sub_class_name": "Sub Member"
            },
            {
                "sub_class_id": 5,
                "sub_class_name": "None"
            }
        ]
 // $scope.class_name = $scope.MemberClass[0];
  
  
 $scope.alertdata = function() {
   $scope.class_name = "{}";
        var parameter;        
        parameter = {
            "member": {
                "first_name": "first_name",

                "role": [{
                    "role_id": 4
                }],

                "associated": "associated",

                "class0": [JSON.parse($scope.class_name)],

                "contect": [{
                    "intercom": "intercom"
                }],

                "individualdetails": [{
                    "gender": "gender"
                }]
            },

            "address": [{
                "street_address_1": "street_address_1"
            }]
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(parameter));
 };       
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitly use ng-options for this

```
<select ng-model="class_name" ng-options="t as t.class_name for t in MemberClass">
</select>
```

To set a default, either set the $scope.class_name to a value of the MemberClass array or you can add an empty option tag as below which will be selected when the $scope.class_name is null

```
<select ng-model="class_name" ng-options="t as t.class_name for t in MemberClass">
  <option value="">Select value</option>
</select>
```